# Proof that the flow of a differential equation tends to $x^\ast$ if $\omega(x_0)=\{x^\ast\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that the limit set of the flow for $t\to\infty$ of some starting point $x_0$ is equal to one point:
$$
\omega(x_0) = \{x^\ast\}
$$
for some $x^\ast$, I want to prove that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \phi(t,x_0) = x^\ast
$$
where $\phi$ is the flow of the solution.

Things I tried: We have 
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty} \phi(t_j, x_0) = x^\ast
$$
for an increasing sequence $t_j$. I already know that the set $\omega(x_0)$ is invariant (this means the whole orbit is in the limit set) so this gives us that $x^\ast$ is a fixpoint. Furthermore I know it has to be closed and connected, but I'm not sure how to use these facts.

Besides: why does this limit even have to exist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just solved the question myself after a hint from my teacher.

Suppose $\omega(x_0) = \{x^\ast\}$. Then we have $\phi(t_n,x_0)\to x^\ast$ for $n\to\infty$ for some sequence $(t_i)_{i=0}^\infty$. Now suppose that $\phi(t,x_0)\not\to x^\ast$. Then we have an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $T$ there exists a $t>T$ such that $$|\phi(t,x_0)-x^\ast|\geq\epsilon.$$ On the other hand, since $\phi(t_n,x_0)\to x^\ast$ the solution will be infinitely many times inside the ball $B(x^\ast,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

Together, this gives us that the flow will cross the compact area $\overline{B(x^\ast,\frac{2\epsilon}{3})}\setminus B(x^\ast,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ infinitely many times. Bolzano-Weierstrass now gives us a limit point inside this area. This is a contradiction with $\omega(x_0)=\{x^\ast\}$. Therefore, $\phi(t,x_0)\to x^\ast$.